# Solar Panel & Temperature coefficient of Voc Seems Exceedingly Low

Tags: solar-cell, temperature-coefficient

I am reading over a solar panel data sheet and I'm having issue converting the Temperature coefficient of Voc as written because it seems exceedingly low to me. I fully understand the panel datasheet might be misleading as well but wanted to ensure my understand of the data provided was correct.

As I understand it most panels should have a temperature coefficient of VOC (open-circuit voltage) of -0.2 to -0.5 closer to absolute 0 being better.

The panel I am reading up on lists the temperature coefficient of VOC as -(80±10)mV/°C  which if I am not mistaken means -0.09/°C to -0.07V/°C. Am I reading the data correctly?

The following is the specifications of the panel incase I am missing some aspect. Thank you for your time.

Maximum power (Pmax) 100W

Voltage at Pmax (Vmp) 19.00V

Current at Pmax (Imp) 5.27A

Open-circuit voltage (Voc) 23.50V

Short-circuit current (Isc) 5.67A

Temperature coefficient of Voc -(80±10)mV/°C

Temperature coefficient of Isc (0.065±0.015)%/ °C

Temperature coefficient of power -(0.5±0.05)%/ °C

NOCT (Air 20°C; Sun 0.8kW/m² wind 1m/s) 47±2°C

Operating temperature -40°C to 85°C

Maximum system voltage 1000V DC

Power tolerance ± 3%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The panel I am reading up on lists the temperature coefficient of VOC
> as -(80±10)mV/°C which if I am not mistaken means -0.09/°C to
> -0.07V/°C. Am I reading the data correctly?

Yes, that is what the data you posted says.

Answer (score 2):

Note the tempco of the forward voltage of a silicon diode is [commonly stated to be -2mV/K.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/forward-voltage#:%7E:text=The%20other%20determinant%20of%20forward,C%20for%20a%20constant%20current.)

So the figures given are what you would expect for 40 silicon diodes connected in series. Which is pretty much what your panel is (it may be only 36 diodes)